# GCC, CMake, precompiled headers and maintaining dependencies

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to figure out how to maintain dependencies of my precompiled headers. It includes `STL` headers, some third-parties like `boost` and some of our rarely changing infrastructure headers.

I came out with something like this

```
SET(PCH_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
SET(PCH_HEADER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/server/server.h)
SET(PCH_DST server.h.gch)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(serverPCH DEPENDS ${PCH_DST})
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${PCH_DST} ${PCH_DEP}
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -x c++-header ${COMMON_CXXFLAGS} ${COMPILER_DEFINITIONS} -std=gnu++1z -c ${PCH_HEADER} -o ${PCH_DST} -I${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include/server -I${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include
                   MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${PCH_HEADER}
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PCH_DIR}
                   COMMENT "Building precompiled header"
                   VERBATIM)
```

Looks like its doing its job and it gets recompiled once the header is edited. However, PCH recompilation is not triggered when one of files included in `server.h` is changed. Is there a way to trigger re-compilation if any of headers included in `server.h` is changed?

Comment: You need to add a dependency on `server.h.gch` for all your `*.o` object files. I don't know how to do that in `cmake`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know how to do it, but 1) it is ugly :) 2) I dont think it will trigger PCH rebuild since from the CMake point of view the server.h.gch is up to date since it knows nothing about its included headers

Comment: You also need to add a dependency from `server.h` and all included headers there to `server.h.gch`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch _dependency from `server.h` and all included headers there to `server.h.gch`_ Shouldn't it be vice versa (i.e. dependency of `server.h.gch` from `server.h`)? I believe I got your wording wrong.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, like adding (and maintaining) myriads of include files in `MAIN_DEPENDENCY`?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with `cmake` to help you more. And I don't like much `cmake` for those reasons

Answer (score 0):

Well, 2 years later. CMake now supports [precompiled headers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_precompile_headers.html) and [unity](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_UNITY_BUILD.html#variable:CMAKE_UNITY_BUILD) builds.